# Modifying bootstrap Popover Html content does not persist

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following popover settings:

**popover icon launcher**

```
 <label id="settings-layout" class="icon-th" rel="popover" data-original-title="Switch Layout"></label>
```

**Popover content**

```
<div id="settings-layout-content" style="display:none;">
                                 <ul style='margin-left:5px;' >
        <li class='popover-list layout-list' data-id="badge">

            <label class='icon-ok' style='color:#6ABD3D !important;position:relative;right:5px;'></label>
            <label class='icon-th' style='position:relative; top:1px;right:4px;'></label>Badge
           </li>

        <li class='popover-list layout-list' data-id="table">

            <label class='icon-ok' style='color:#6ABD3D !important;position:relative;right:5px;'></label>
            <label class='icon-table' style='position:relative; top:1px;right:4px;'></label>Table

        </li>

    </ul>
   </div>
```

***Script That assign content to popover**

```
$('.icon-th').popover({
            html: true, placement: 'bottom',
            trigger: 'manual', content: function () { return $('#settings-layout-content').html(); }
        }).click(function (e) {
            $('.icon-font').popover('hide');
            $('.icon-filter').popover('hide');
            $(this).popover('toggle');
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

Now when I click on one of the li inside the content of the popover I modify the content as follow:

```
$('.layout-list').live('click', function () {


            $(this).find(">:first-child").addClass("display");

        });
```

This works fine. But when I close the popover and click on the icon to show the popover again, the changes are not persisted.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are sending a copy of the `#settings-layout-content` html to the Popover plugin to display. When you click on the list item in your popup the changes get applied to the elements that were copied and when the popup is closed those elements get destroyed.

To keep the changes you need to apply them to the original element that you are copying into the popup content:

```
// .live() is deprecated, use .on() instead
$(document).on('click', '.layout-list', function () {

    // get clicked item index used to matched the same element in the original content
    var itemIndex = $(this).index();

    // get original element that holds the popover content
    var orig = $('#settings-layout-content').find('.layout-list:eq(' + itemIndex + ')');

    // add the class to the original content
    orig.children(":first").addClass("display");

    // close the popover
    $('#settings-layout').popover('hide');
});
```

Also [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated, it's advised to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) from now on.

Here's a DEMO of how that works: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdJUC/1/