# Jquery dropdown with multiple checkboxes does not save the state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown which has multiple checkboxes. When I close and reopen it, the checkboxes are all unchecked by default. I want to see which checkboxes are checked previously when I reopen the dropdown

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/19rzxg1v/

HTML :

```
 <ul class="inline unstyled">
     <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle select-value" data-placement="bottom">
             -- Select values to show -- <b class="pull-right caret"></b>
         </a>
     </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="popover_select_values" style='display: none'>
    <ul class="scrollable-menu unstyled">
              <li>
                  <label class="checkbox1"> checkbox1
                     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"/>
                  </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <label class="checkbox1"> checkbox2
                     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"/>
                  </label>
              </li>
                  <li>
                  <label class="checkbox1"> checkbox3
                     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3"/>
                  </label>
              </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

JQuery :

```
   $('.select-value').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function () {
    return $('#popover_select_values').html();
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Persist Checkboxes in Bootstrap Popovers Across Openings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27339750/persist-checkboxes-in-bootstrap-popovers-across-openings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED ANSWER:**

It gets the index of current checkbox and changes the corresponding main checkbox accordingly. It'll work regardless of their IDs:

```
$(document).on('change', '.popover-content input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    var idx = $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type=checkbox]').index(this);
    var mainCbs = $('#popover_select_values input[type=checkbox]');
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
       mainCbs.eq(idx).attr('checked', 'checked');
    else
        mainCbs.eq(idx).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/19rzxg1v/6/)

**OLD ANSWER:**

```
$(document).on('change', '.popover-content input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    var idx = parseInt($(this).prop('id').split('checkbox')[1])-1;
    var mainCbs = $('#popover_select_values input[type=checkbox]');
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
       mainCbs.eq(idx).attr('checked', 'checked');
    else
        mainCbs.eq(idx).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/19rzxg1v/1/)

Comment: Check the edited answer, it'll work regardless of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The way the popover works is that it creates a new version of the content every time you click on the link. It takes the HTML and copies it.

You could instead use the dropdown plugin?

Alternatively you can store the selected values when the popover is closed and set them again when you open it. You can do that using the 
`shown.bs.popover` and `hidden.bs.popover` events.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I use a dropdown plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the state of checkboxes checked. Try the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/lolptdr/aof88p65/#base

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="button-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>  <span class="caret"></span>

            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 1</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 2</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var options = [];
$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function (event) {

var $target = $(event.currentTarget),
    val = $target.attr('data-value'),
    $inp = $target.find('input'),
    idx;

if ((idx = options.indexOf(val)) > -1) {
    options.splice(idx, 1);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $inp.prop('checked', false)
    }, 0);
} else {
    options.push(val);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $inp.prop('checked', true)
    }, 0);
}

$(event.target).blur();
    console.log(options);
    return false;
});
```